# flask mysql SUM() Decimal in Dictionary from cursor.fetchone()

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sum, decimal

I'am connecting my flask-app to a MySQL-Database like this:

```
from flask_mysql_connector import MySQL
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL


# MySQL Connection
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'Prices'
app.config['MYSQL_PORT'] = 3306
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_SOCKET'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_UNIX_SOCKET'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_READ_DEFAULT_FILE'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_USE_UNICODE'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_CHARSET'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_SQL_MODE'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'


mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)
```

Performing a query like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(total) AS sumy FROM tbl")
total = cursor.fetchone()
total = total["sumy"]
```

returns this:

```
({'sumy': Decimal('123.4')})
```

My Questions now are:

Does every connector, the

```
MySQL Connector/Python
PyMySQL
MySQLDB
mysqlclient
and the OurSQL
```

return a Decimal('123.4') Value from a SUM(column) query?
How would I get rid of this Decimal-feature the easy way? I know there are CAST() and float() suggestions out there.
I like to keep it simple so is there maybe a fetchone() parameter I am missing?
Or a connection parameter like ['raw'] as the MySQL Connector/Python has(I'd have to rewrite my code, if I had to change to that...)

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, funny as it may seem, even the SUM of floats is returned as Decimal(123.4). I so went on doing all calculations in MySQL and using flask only to show the content.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal is the python way of representing fixed decimal values. The SQL is returning a decimal probably because the `sumy` is decimal. Its likely all implementation will handle this the same way.

Leaving the python application to handle it as a `Decimal` is probably the best way to maintain the database being responsible for retrieval and the application for presentation.

Answer (score -2):

USE FOR LOOP

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
import MySQLdb

db= MySQLdb.connect("hostname", "username", "password", "database_name")

cursor= db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(price) AS totalsum FROM CustomerOrders")

result = cursor.fetchall()

for i in result:
print(i[0])

db.close()